# Regexp - php - check if there is are references to .php files (but not includes)

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a regular expression for finding out if a file contains references to .php files, and if it does, I want to collect the file names. However, I have to skip all the includes and requires. For instance in the following example:

```
include_once "inc/config.php" ;

include 'inc/php/curl.php' ;

<a href="/index.php">test</a>
if($b == 'test2.php'){
   $c = 4;
}

require_once "inc/php/mail.php" ;    

//$e = $d == 'blabla.php' ? 1 : 2;
```

The matches should be:

> index.php, test2.php, blabla.php

All the includes and requires must be skipped.
Do you have any idea how to write such regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would have done it:

```
(?<!include\s|include_once\s|require_once\s)["'](?:.*?\/?)(.*\.php)["']
```

This will give you the file names only (as requested).

Regards.

Edit:

`(?:(?:include|require)(?:_once)?\s+["'](?:.*?\/?).*\.php["']|["'](?:.*?\/?)(.*\.php)["'])`

will do the trick without the negative lookbehind (thus working in JS as well) and handles an arbitrary number of spaces before the quoted name.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match only lines which contain ".php" and not start with `include_once`  `include` `require_once`

```
^(?!include_once)(?!include)(?!require_once).+([\w].php)
```